# Calculus of Variations: Hamilton’s canonical equations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

In Calculus of Variations, Hamilton’s canonical equations (*Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory* by Daniel Liberzon, p. 45) are

$$y'~=~H_p,\tag{1}$$
   $$p'~=~-H_y.\tag{2}$$

I understand the second equation requires the Euler-Lagrange equation, but I think the first equation doesn't need the E-L equation. If so, any $y$ (optimal or not) can satisfy the first equation. Then, I wonder why we need the first equation?

Answer (score 0):

Where [Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) typically are 2nd order [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)s in the $y$-variables, the [Hamilton's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) are twice as many 1st order ODEs in twice as many variables $(y,p)$.

So yes, we also need OP's eq. (1): It's the relation between velocity $y^{\prime}$ and momentum $p$. It is needed in order to turn OP's eq. (2) into Lagrange equation.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451) related Phys.SE post.